# 456789345 is my input i want to get it as (456) 789-345 as output in sql server using functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, function, tags

456789345 is my input i want to get it as (456)  789-345 as output in sql server using functions..

Comment: This looks like job for application layer. In SQL Server 2012+ you can use `FORMATMESSAGE` **[DEMO](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/411827)**

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the questioner made no effort at all to solve the problem himself.

Comment: This is a simple question and there are good answers.

Answer (score 4):

In SQL Server, you can do this using `stuff()` or other string operations:

```
select '(' + stuff(stuff(@input, 7, 0, '-'), 4, 0, ') ')
```

Comment: Works even if `456789345` is an `int`

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @t varchar(20) = '456789345'


select '('+SUBSTRING(@t,1,3)+')' +' '+ SUBSTRING(@t,4,3) +'-'+ SUBSTRING(@t,6,3)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
declare @var VARCHAR(MAX) = '456789345'

select '('+SUBSTRING(@var,1,3)+')'+' '+SUBSTRING(@var,4,3)+'-'+SUBSTRING(@var,6,3)
```

Comment: This is pretty much a repeat of [this existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34356338/456789345-is-my-input-i-want-to-get-it-as-456-789-345-as-output-in-sql-server/34356413#34356413).